# Non-Integer Numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I incorporate non-integer numbers into tikz?

e.g. Drawing a line segment from (0,0) to (1/(sqrt2),1/(sqrt2))

My method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  % Line Segment
  \draw (0,0) -- ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives an error. I know that a possibility is to write it as (0.707,0.707), and if all else fails I can fall back to using that, but I'd prefer a more exact way.

Comment: `$\frac{}{}$` is for *typesetting*, it's not function that does calculations. `({1/sqrt(2)}, {1/sqrt(2)})`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, that works. :-)